# Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 and platform X86. Following DLL(s) do not match framework/platform

Tags: .net, dll, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, vstest.console.exe

We're able to run unit tests & publish the code coverage to sonarqube in Azure Devops build pipeline till last month. Now we're getting the below error in Visual Studio Test task for .NET code.

> Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 and platform X86. Following DLL(s) do not
> match framework/platform settings. MedicareActuarial.Api.Tests.dll is
> built for Framework 3.1 and Platform AnyCPU.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.dll is built for Framework 3.1 and
> Platform AnyCPU. Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.dll is
> built for Framework 1.4 and Platform AnyCPU.
> Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.dll is built for Framework 1.4
> and Platform AnyCPU. Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.dll is
> built for Framework 1.4 and Platform AnyCPU.
> Microsoft.TestPlatform.PlatformAbstractions.dll is built for Framework
> 1.0 and Platform AnyCPU. Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common.dll is built for Framework
> 1.4 and Platform AnyCPU. Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.dll is built for
> Framework 1.4and Platform AnyCPU. testhost.dll is built for Framework
> 1.0 and Platform AnyCPU.

We've tried options Override test run parameters/other console options with the above specific .dlls in test files. but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The same issues happen on **previous** version of `Visual Studio 16.2`. It has fixed on `Visual Studio 16.2` [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/test-discovery-reporting-dlls-do-not-match/579073)

If you are facing the same issue Try to use the latest Visual Studio version https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

People who are faced similar issue with solution. Check here for [additional information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50223282/tfs-tests-do-not-match-framework-settings)